# A strangeness with a:link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

My HTML :

```
<a href="http://google.fr">Google</a><br>
<a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
```

CSS :

```
a:link {
text-decoration: none
}
```

I would style only unvisited links (logically, a:link styles unvisited links), but even visited links lose underlining. Why?

Update : JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/M8AyL/

Comment: Maybe try to force visted link style with a:visited

Comment: a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M8AyL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hashem Qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami) says in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160869/a-strangeness-with-alink#comment37288398_24160977), [MDN states the reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited):

> **Note:** For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you
>   can apply using an element selected by `:visited` pseudo-class:
>
> only `color`,
>   `background-color`, `border-color`, `border-bottom-color`,
>   `border-left-color`, `border-right-color`, `border-top-color`,
>   `outline-color`, `column-rule-color`, `fill` and `stroke`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because there is no other property set for a link. Hence all the visited links too are getting hit by a:link.

```
a:visited {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

for the desired result.

Comment: what system are you working on? It seems to work on my system.

Comment: @user3546093 seems weird to me, It works well on IE but not on the latest version of Google Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/M8AyL/1/
In fact, `text-decoration: underline;` is not applied but you can see that the color changes.

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome. I tried Firefox, but it was the same thing.

Comment: @user3546093 Oh I found out [the reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited): ***Note:** For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, `border-bottom-color`, `border-left-color`, `border-right-color`, `border-top-color`, `outline-color`, `column-rule-color`, fill and stroke.*
IE sucks!

Comment: @Hashem Qolami Unfortunately, I can't accept comments as anwers on this site. Thanks!

Comment: @user3546093 Don't mention it, Thank you. I learned something new today.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami "IE sucks" I agree. :D

Comment: @user3546093 only webkit-based browsers don't suck, both IE and the so-called FireFox suck, personally I feel FireFox sucks much more than what IE sucks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the `:visited` pseudo element because [MDN for `:link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alink) states :

> The :link CSS pseudo-class lets you select links inside elements. This will select any link [...]

Answer (score 0):

> The :link CSS pseudo-class lets you select links inside elements. This will select any link, even those already styled using selector with other link-related pseudo-classes like :hover, :active or :visited. **In order to style only non-visited links, you need to put the :link rule before the other ones, as defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.** The :focus pseudo-class is usually placed right before or right after :hover, depending of the expected effect.

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alink)

Now will be a good time to quit learning from misleading sources like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp)

Comment: Thanks but "The :link selector does not style links you have already visited" - your link

Comment: @user3546093 i didn't get you..?